# how to get the short version of file name till the second underscore in excel

Tags: excel, split, concatenation

I am looking for an easy way to get the short version of the filename value till the second underscore in the required column.

I tried text to the column but it is a long process to split them first then concate.
so now following the **=left** code process.

need to automate this process, is it possible to directly get the short version till the second underscore directly.

[As you can see, due to 1 less character the underscore is coming at the end in the required field. and that is not required.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ5fK.jpg)

[manually have to change the value to 9 to remove the ending underscore and get the correct output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ3cm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy trick to find the second occurence of a character in a string in Excel:

```
=SEARCH("_";A1;SEARCH("_";A1)+1)
```

First, it searches for an underscore in A1, and then an underscore is searched for in A1 again, starting from one place further.

Comment: I tried the search formula but not getting the result.
I am looking for the file name to be trimmed.
ex - 
if 'AGO_BL3108_LUAXXX_TORXE_AXXXNTE' is file name then its output i want is 'AGO_BL3108'
if 'ARE_12270_ABXXXI_CULXXXND' is file name then its output i want is  'ARE_12270'.

this is possible with the "=Left" formula but it is a lengthy process as the File name letter count is not constant.